# how to bind gridview array list in android from sqlite data

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

```
public void addHeader(){
    String items[]={ "DATE", "INCOME","EXPENCE","PROFIT","LOSS","REMARKS"};
    for (String strText:items) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("ItemText",strText);
        srcTable.add(map);
   }
    saTable.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}

public void addData(){

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        String items[]={ "12/10/2013", "500","100","400","000","GOOD"};
        for (String strText:items) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("ItemText",strText);
            srcTable.add(map);
       }    
    }
    saTable.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I the above code i want to get data from databse using adddata() function , For that which query i have to pass instead of "500", "100" etc....

Comment: I feel that the closing comment is very vague. You have declared a fixed String array of items but you want to use this String array to get sqlite database values? *confused*

Do you mean to say that you want to get sqlite data in the format "DATE", "INCOME","EXPENCE","PROFIT","LOSS","REMARKS" so you may write it to your gridview list?

Maybe this link would help...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: This query is working fine...